# How to scroll one page at a time in Linux at the command line?

Tags: linux

In windows, you could do a

`dir | more`

to scroll one page a time.  How does one do this in Linux?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The same `ls | more` although most people use the `ls | less` command as it has more features, such as scrolling back as well as forwards, and searching for text.

To scroll forwards a screen press space. To scroll back a screen press 'b'. To search for some text type `/something`.

And as always `man less` for more details.

Comment: Always remember: less is more than more, not less :)

Comment: so less is more.. I like this unixious trick

Comment: Great answer!  After you answered, I realized that I really meant to ask this question: http://superuser.com/questions/198790/how-to-scroll-one-page-at-a-time-in-asterisk-at-the-command-line

Comment: And type `q` to quit.

Answer (score 4):

First, the equivalent to Windows's `dir` is `ls` (to see just file names) or `ls -l` (to see file names and metadata).

Often you don't need to do anything at all as most terminal environment let you scroll back a few hundreds of lines (depending on configuration) using a scroll bar or (often) with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PgUp</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PgDn</kbd>.

If you have very long output or want to search, you can pipe into `more` (i.e. `ls -l | more`) the same way you did on Windows, but most people use `less` (`ls -l | less`), an improvement on `more` which gets its name from its ability to also go backwards (amongst other features). Another less common alternative to `more` is `most`.